# C++ use std::fill for class with deleted assign operator

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a range of objects

```
class X {
public:
    X()
        : X(0) {
    }
    X(size_t num)
        : x_(num) {
    }
    X(const X& other) = delete;
    X& operator=(const X& other) = delete;
    X(X&& other) {
        x_ = exchange(other.x_, 0);
    }
    X& operator=(X&& other) {
        x_ = exchange(other.x_, 0);
        return *this;
    }
    size_t GetX() const {
        return x_;
    }

private:
    size_t x_;
};
```

With this in mind I can't use std::fill as operator= is deleted. What is the right way to fill the range for this kind of object?

Comment: Looks like you have a move only class, so construct another array of X, then move it into your obj.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source object of `std::fill` is `const`. *const* object cannot be used as source of move operation.

You can add helper class with conversion operator to `X`, every time when `*first = value;` (look at [possible implementation of std::fill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)) is called, temporary of X is returned and move operation is performed:

```
template<size_t N>
struct Helper {
    X MakeTemp() const { return X(N); }
    operator X () const { return MakeTemp(); }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<X> v;
    v.resize(10);
    std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(),Helper<10>{});
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GsWxj9)

Comment: Great approach, thanks a lot - and what about std::copy usage for this case?

Comment: I would use `std::generate_n` for this rather than `fill` as that's more descriptive.

Comment: @Dmitry If you want to copy of collection, use `std::move` algorithm instead.